# Delayed "let" in SICP

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, lisp

In section 3.5.4 , i saw this block:

```
(define (integral delayed-integrand initial-value dt)
    (define int
        (cons-stream initial-value
            (let ((integrand (force delayed-integrand)))
                (add-streams (scale-stream integrand dt)
                    int))))
int)
```

Normally if this was something like:

```
(define (stream-map proc s)
    (if (stream-null? s)
        the-empty-stream
            (cons-stream (proc (stream-car s))
                (stream-map proc (stream-cdr s)))))
```

The `stream-cdr s` would be evaluated as `(cons-stream (stream-car (cdr s)) delay<>)` even when the actual call would be in a delay. ie even though the stream-map function itself is delayed, the arguments are pre-computed.

Then why is `let` not pre-computed?

**What I think?**
I think `let` is a lambda function with no arguments, so its execution is delayed

Can someone please help me confirm this?